# Arrange expanded/shrunk rectangles in a 2D space

Tags: java, algorithm

In a 2D space, there are some rectangles. They will grow or shrink, some will grow/shrink simultaneously. When a rectangle grows, its top-left corner will never move, i.e. only the bottom or right edge can move.

We need to re-position overlapped rectangles. We want to make sure the re-positioned 2D space is visually similar to the previous space (i.e. we should not shuffle them, should not introduce unnecessary blank spaces, (if it is possible) should not change each rectangles' closest rectangles).

Known values:

- size of the space
- distance between two adjacent rectangles
- sizes of rectangles (size before & after changing)
- position of rectangles

How can rectangles be efficiently re-positioned? What algorithm should be used so that a group of collisions can be solved by one operation (because some rectangles may be well aligned and have the same size)? How can we guess the relationship between adjacent rectangles based on their coordinates, and re-position them smartly.

Some examples:

- case 1: grow/shrink vertically (Simple)
- case 2: grow/shrink horizontally (Complicated. It assumes there are 2 rectangle groups, `left` and `right`, rather than `top` and `bottom`. When `left` changes, `right` is re-positioned as shown in the figure below.)
- case 3: grow/shrink horizontally (Simple)

[image: Examples]

**Current solution**

```
 //required values: distance between two adjacent rectangles, sizes of rectangles
 sort(rectangles) // from top-left to bottom-right
 foreach (rect in rectangles)
     if (distance between two adjacent rectangles changed)
         get number of grown/shrunk rows/columns
         foreach (rect2 in rectangles below/to the right of rect)
             move rect2 according to the grown/shrunk rows
             if collision is solved after vertical movement
                 continue
             else
                 move horizontally
```

This solution fails in case 2, because the relative distances of small blue rectangle is changed, but its size is not changed. The distance between the bottom two rectangles will not be 0.

Comment: *"It would be perfect if the relative positions/distance between two rectangles are not changed in some cases"* - I think you really need to clarify the meaning of 'relative position' and 'some cases' in order to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several approaches (I have thought about this problem for approximately more than a month) and I found the following method may be better.
I suppose we must know the relationship between rectangles (how they are grouped) in order to make the re-positioned rectangles visually similar to previous version.

```
// Use 2D array to represent the 2D space
ConstructRectangleGroups()
foreach (item in array) // item is the pixel in 2D space
    if (item contains more than 1 rectangles) // has collision
        foreach (rect in item's rectangles)
            get number of rect's grown/shrunk rows/columns
            foreach (rect2 in rectangleGroups[rectangleGroups.FindIndex(rect)])
                move rect2 according to the grown/shrunk rows
                if collision is solved after vertical movement
                    continue
                else
                    move horizontally
```

ConstructRectangleGroups() is

```
rectangleGroups = [][]
foreach (item in array)
    if (item has rectangle)
        closestRectangles = rectangle.GetClosestRectangles()
        // A rectangle is isolated if the distance between adjacent rectangle > MaxDistance
        // In this case, closestRectangles will be empty.
        if (closestRectangles.Count > 0)
            foreach (closestRectangle in closestRectangles)
                if (closestRectangle.ClosestRectangle != rectangle)
                    rectangle.ClosestRectangle = closestRectangle
            if (rectangle.closestRectangle == null)
                rectangle.ClosestRectangle = closestRectangles[0]
foreach (rect in rectangles)
    if (rect.ClosestRectangle == null)
        rectangleGroups.Add(new [] { rect })
    else
        index = rectangle.FindIndex(rect)
        if (index < 0)
            rectangleGroups.Add(new [] { rect })
        else
            rectangleGroups[index].Add(rect.ClosestRectangle)
```